# Time averaged fluctuation of an operator

Tags: statistical-mechanics

For an operator $A$ we can say that $$\langle A(t) \rangle = \langle\psi(t)| A | \psi(t) \rangle = \sum_{\alpha \beta} C_{\alpha}^* C_{\beta}e^{i(E_{\alpha} - E_{\beta})t / \hbar} A_{\alpha \beta}$$ and

$$ \bar{A} = lim_{\tau \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{\tau} \int_{0}^{\tau} dt \langle A(t) \rangle = \sum_{\alpha}|C_{\alpha}|^2 A_{\alpha \alpha}$$

which I understand comes from phase cancellation.

I am having trouble understanding the following

$$
\begin{aligned}
\overline{[\langle A(t)\rangle-\bar{A}]^2} & \equiv \lim _{\tau \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{\tau} \int_0^\tau \mathrm{d} t[\langle A(t)\rangle-\bar{A}]^2 \\
& =\sum_{\alpha, \beta \neq \alpha}\left|C_\alpha\right|^2\left|C_\beta\right|^2\left|A_{\alpha \beta}\right|^2 .
\end{aligned}
$$

mainly because when I square out the terms and integrate everything I'm left with
$$ lim_{\tau \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{\tau} \int_{0}^{\tau} \sum_{\alpha \neq \beta} \sum_{\gamma \neq \delta} C_{\alpha}^* C_{\delta}^* C_\beta C_\gamma e^{i[(E_\alpha + E_\delta) - (E_\beta + E_\gamma)]t / \hbar } A_{\alpha \beta} A_{\gamma \delta}^*$$

which I believe should reduce to the necessary final line, but I'm not seeing how. Phase cancellation wouldn't occur when $E_\alpha + E_{\delta} = E_\beta + E_{\gamma}$ but that doesn't directly imply the final line. What am I missing here?